# random access gpgpu performance drop?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

I've heard there is a drop in performance when performing computations on arrays with random access on a gpu.

My question is how severe is this performance drop?

Searching around some comments seemed to imply code ran faster on cpu.  But seeing the vast difference in int and flop between gpus and cpus it seems difficult to believe performance would drop so bad.

Comment: Make an experiment. Add two arrays in a coalesced way, then non coalesced.

Comment: Will try when I get my new card, sold current card in anticipation of rtx and currently running on igpu.

Answer (score 2):

I think that it is related to cache loss. GPU also has L1 L2 caches and if you hit random memory space, then you will have more chance to lose cache. And also because GPU has special memory access pattern that called memory coalescing. It is accessing memory with wide range. It is why GPU is so fast when they run SIMD friendly code. But if you access random memory space, it will break memory coalescing. I think that it would be good to read cuda document to see how GPU works.

Comment: Thanks.   I will read more on the documentation to clarify.   The thing is I'm working on a program where array locations might change at runtime, and was wondering just how severe the drop in performance would be.   Because potentially I think it could be designed or split to do the random access manipulation step in the cpu and the non random access computations on the gpu if the performance drop is severe enough on gpus.